# Adding multiple jQuery/DOM elements to single jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I have references to multiple divs and I want to add them all to ONE jQuery object at once.

These things don't work...

```
>>> $( $e1, $e2, $e3 )
[div]

>>> $([ $e1, $e2, $e3 ])
[[div], [div], [div]]

>>> $().add($e1, $e2, $e3)
[div]

>>> $().add([ $e1, $e2, $e3 ])
[[div], [div], [div]]
```

However this works:

```
>>> $().add($e1).add($e2).add($e3)
[div, div, div]

>>> $e1.add($e2).add($e3)
[div, div, div]
```

But I want more elegant solution.

Comment: what are $el1 $el2 and $el3? Dom elements previously chosen by jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you push them in an array?

Comment: And how do I make a jQuery object out of that array (elegantly)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery does allow you to add a bunch of elements at once to a jquery object, but only when those elements are pure DOM elements, not jquery objects themselves.

```
var $e1 = $('#x'),
    $e2 = $('#y'),
    $e3 = $('#z');

var e1 = $e1[0],
    e2 = $e2[0],
    e3 = $e3[0];


>>> $( [$el, $e2, $e3] )    // does not work
[[div], [div], [div]]       // jquery object that contains other jQuery objects

>>> $( [el, e2, e3] )       // works
[div, div, div]             // jquery object that contains pure DOM objects
```

When we pass an array of jquery objects to `jQuery()`, they are NOT "unwrapped" before adding them to the result jquery object.

Also remember, however, that passing a single jquery object makes the unwrapping happen.

```
>>> $( $e1 )
[div]                       // returns a jquery object
```

Interestingly, if we mix jquery and pure DOM objects, only the pure objects are operated upon:

```
>>> $( [$e1, e2, $e3] ).css('background-color', '#000');
```

Note above that second element is a pure DOM element and the background color is only applied to that second element.

The bottom line is: if you want to add multiple elements to a jquery object at once, add pure DOM object, not jquery objects.

Comment: jquery failed me here

Answer (score 2):

Loop over array using each:

```
$.each([ $e1, $e2, $e3 ], function(i, $el){
    $el.doSomething()
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/REXmh/

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to make array of these objects and push that into a variable.

```
var $a = $('<div/>').attr('class','box');
var $b = $('<div/>').attr('class','box');
var $c = $('<div/>').attr('class','box');
var $d = $('<div/>').attr('class','box');

var $arr = [$a, $b, $c, $d];

$.each($arr, function(i, el){
  $(el).text('asdf').appendTo('body');
});
```

plz checkout the fiddle:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/nvRVG/1/**

Comment: so what do you want adding same text in every div